# If and else statement in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, button, textview, android-edittext

Ok I have an issue with the logic of the `if and else statement` I am not understanding why and how the logic doesn't work. I have used the statement in other programming but this is what I am wanting to do.

I am using a button with my sqrt function. In the button I am trying to use an escape route. When I press the button it gives the square root. However when I press the button again it crashes.

So for a temporary fix and learning purpose I have done this:

```
 binding.btnSqrt.setOnClickListener{
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.####")
    if(!tv_equation.text.isNullOrEmpty())
    {
        val number = tv_equation.text.toString().toDouble()
        binding.tvResult.text = df.format(sqrt(number))
    else
      { 
       binding.tvResult.text = ""
      binding.tvEquation.append("")
}
```

However it does not imply the `if else statement`. I am looking at this how the statement works in WPF and UWP.

When I press the button again after that it just doubles the answer. For example in tvResult if I have 4 then when the button is pressed again it should clear but what it does is double and adds what ever is there so it shows 44 instead of clearing the textview and edittext.

Am I using the if and else statement wrong in kotlin. Or is it just the way the button is originally coded?

Comment: Honestly, by looking at your code I don't really understand the logic behind it and what is it supposed to do. `if ... else` in Kotlin works as in any other language.

Comment: @broot it's a calculator so that is the square root function. But what I am wanting to do is clear the text when the Sqrt button is pressed again. If you look at my question Square Root you will understand the button part

Comment: I read your question, but your code does a much different thing than you described, so I'm not sure if I misunderstood the description or the code just doesn't at all fit the description. The only thing it does is to calculate the square root, but I don't see how it could clear the text after the second click. Maybe try to describe what you expect this code to do line after line. Why do you expect it to clear the field after the second click?

Comment: How does the click listener know if it's been clicked before? All you're checking is whether there's something in the ``equation`` text field, and if there is, you append it to the ``result`` text (i.e. stick it on the end of whatever's there). You're not clearing the equation after that, so next click it will still have contents in it, and the ``if`` condition will be true again. Maybe you wanted to clear that?